# How to load language from sharedpreference on activity startup in android?

Tags: android

I am saving user selected language in sharedpreference. when i close the app and restart it i read the value in sharedpreference by getValue method, and try to change the language. But my activity is stuck in loop.

I check this in onCreate

```
   String language = getValue(getBaseContext());
       if (language!= null && !language.isEmpty()) {
        changelanguage(language);
       }
```

changeLanguage is as:

```
private void changelanguage(String languageToLoad) {
    Locale  myLocale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
    finish();
    save(this, languageToLoad);
}
```

How can i read and load user saved language on startup?

Comment: where are you saving the language in sharedprefernces, you can share some code with us

Comment: You're starting the new activity, but only save the language the newly opening activity should use two lines below (assuming your `save()` method simply does a `SharedPreferences.Editor.commit()`)

Comment: public void save(Context context, String text) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        editor = settings.edit(); //2

        editor.putString(PREFS_KEY, text);
        editor.commit(); 
    }
    public String getValue(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        String text;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
        text = settings.getString(PREFS_KEY, null); //2
        return text;
    }

Comment: I use save() function for saving selected language in sharedpreference. GetValue() method for loading the previously saved value. The methods are given above.

Comment: My guess is " Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
    finish(); ", this is causing the loop. So how can i set the language when user restarts the app?

Comment: one more thing, ChangeLanguage works perfectly when it is cqlled from actionbar's button after the app is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i solved it by setting the language in oncreate just before the UI is inflated.

Answer (score 0):

you are restart your intend in on create method this result in infinite loop .just remove
 `Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
    finish();`
this code .hope this will help you

Comment: But i need this when user changes the language from action bar button, otherwise the screen is not refreshed after selecting the language. i am calling the same method from onCreate when activity is started and from onOptionsItemSelected when user is changing it. I just dont know howto check if the method is called from onCreate.

Comment: start this activity from onOptionItemSelected method but not from on create otherwise it always stuck in loop.

Comment: then how can i load the language on app startup from sharedpreference?

Comment: get value from sharedpreference if it does't contain any value then you have to call this method from onOptionItemSelected otherwise if it contain any value set that language in on create method itself